# How to find the size of file

Tags: bash

```
FILE=a.txt 
FILE_SIZE = `stat -c %s $FILE`

if [ $FILESIZE >= 1000  ]; then 

   cp $FILE /tmp/

   # How to empty file ? 

then
```

I am trying to get size of file and if the size is over limited and  cp those file and  empty the same file

How to acheive this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably be better off doing something like:

```
mv ${FILE} ${FILE}.staging
```

since that'll be near-atomic in duration.

Then `mv` it to the `tmp` filesystem after that while processes will recreate a new `${FILE}`.

Keep in mind that, if you have a long lived process writing to `${FILE}`, it will *continue* to write to `${FILE}.staging` after the first move.

But, if you just have a lot of processes which open/write/close your file, the atomic move is probably the safest way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo > $FILE
```

But be aware that if something is still writing to the file, you'll lose the output that happens between the `cp` and the `echo`.